# Mixer datasheet plots

Tags: datasheet, mixer

I am trying to read datasheets of mixers...

For the plots in datasheets, for example Conversion Loss/Gain vs frequency, is that frequency RF or LO?

Analog Devices labels the x-axis as RF frequency clearly 
(http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/admv1012.pdf),

but some datasheet don't label anything
(http://www.skyworksinc.com/uploads/documents/201017D.pdf)

Can I assume that the x-axis-frequency always refers to RF frequency? Is there any case that LC vs LO frequency is important?

Answer (score 0):

Generally the IF frequency is so low that there's very little difference between the RF and LO frequencies, at the level that would cause a significant error in reading the conversion loss curve.

In the case of the specific Analog Devices mixer you quote, an LO doubler is used, so they have to be careful to label the axes.

Comment: Yes, RF freq and LO freq are very closed to give much lower frequency. So it makes senses that they don't specify what freq the x-axis is. Thanks @Neil_UK.